# Not able to set number of shuffle partition in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know that by default, the number of partition for tasks is set to 200 in spark. I can't seem to change this. I'm running jupyter with spark 1.6.

I'm loading a fairly small table with about 37K rows from hive using the following in my notebook

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10")
test= sqlContext.table('some_table')
print test.rdd.getNumPartitions()
print test.count()
```

The output confirms 200 tasks. From the activity log, it's spinning up 200 tasks, which is an overkill. it seems like line number 2 above is ignored. So, I tried the following:

```
test = sqlContext.table('gfcctdmn_work.icgdeskrev_emma_cusip_activity_bw').repartition(5)
```

and create a new cell:

```
print test.rdd.getNumPartitions()
print test.count()
```

The output shows 5 partitions, but the log shows 200 tasks being spun up for the count, and then repartition  to 5 took place after. However, if I convert it first to RDD, and back to DataFrame as follow:

```
 test = sqlContext.table('gfcctdmn_work.icgdeskrev_emma_cusip_activity_bw').repartition(5).rdd
```

and create a new cell:

```
print test.getNumPartitions()
print test.toDF().count()
```

The very first time I ran the new cell, it's still running with 200 tasks. However, the second time I ran the new cell, it ran with 5 tasks.

How can I make the code run with 5 tasks the very first time it's running?

Would you mind explaining why this behaves this way(specifying number of partition, but it's still running under default settings)? Is it because the defauly Hive table was created using 200 partitions?

Comment: Spark, deterministic behavior. Choose one... More seriously, if you want a Spark property to be enforced _"the very first time"_, then set it in the configuration used at startup -- i.e. either in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` or on the command line, with `--conf <prop>=<value>`. Or if you can't customize your Jupyter kernel, then inside your Notebbok, close your "SparkContext" then re-create it with a modified conf (but it's a bit tricky)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. It's still spinning up 200 tasks. pyspark --num-executors 2 --executor-memory=16G --conf spark.default.parallelism=15

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your notebook, do something like this:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
sc.stop()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", 10)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

When the notebook starts you have already a `SparkContext` created for you, but still you can change configuration and recreate it.

As for `spark.default.parallelism`, I understand it is what you need, take a look [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/configuration.html):

> Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like
>   join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set by user.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried this, but i'm getting an error. when recreating the context

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Delegation Token can be issued only with kerberos authentication. Current AuthenticationMethod: TOKEN)

Comment: Well, for me it works, you must have different authentication. Doing a quick search I saw [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11472), they're talking about the shell not the notebook, but there's a not-recommended-workaround... Sorry I cannot really help you further, since I cannot even reproduce it. Good luck!