# Unable to change number of partitions in Pyspark with Spark 3.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Pyspark on Spark 3.0.1 on Windows 10 locally for testing and developing, and regardless of what I try the number of processes spawned is always 200 which is way too many for my small test cases.

I'm creating my Spark-SQL context like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_test").master("local")\
            .config('spark.shuffle.partitions', '16')\
            .config('spark.adaptive.enabled', 'True')\
            .config("spark.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled", "True").getOrCreate()
```

Doing `print(spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll())` later shows that the parameters have been correctly set (host censored by me):

```
[('spark.master', 'local'), 
 ('spark.driver.host', '**************'), 
 ('spark.app.name', 'pyspark_test'), 
 ('spark.adaptive.enabled', 'True'), 
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'), 
 ('spark.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled', 'True'), 
 ('spark.driver.port', '58352'), 
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'), 
 ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''), 
 ('spark.shuffle.partitions', '16'), 
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'), 
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'), 
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1602571079244')]
```

I'm executing the task using `spark-submit` in the console, so each SparkSession should be created new with the given config.

My code contains a `groupBy`, an inner `join`, and a `write.csv` at the end. The csv output is the main issue here.

When I do a `coalesce(1)` before writing csv it takes 3 minutes to collect 200 pieces of data into one, the output csv has 338KB. In the Stages Overview I can see that it only runs 2 tasks in parallel while going through the 200 pieces. Without that it just writes 200 separate csv files with 2KB each which also takes around 3 minutes.

My input data is two csv files with the sizes 3.8MB and 826KB.

I tried this with and without enabling adaptive optimization, but it feels like my settings are being ignored anyway.

I am aware of [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792276/not-able-to-set-number-of-shuffle-partition-in-pyspark) but that was three and a half years ago on V1.6.

Also I did experiment with first creating a SparkContext, setting and getting a conf, stopping the SparkContext and using the conf for my SparkSession, but that didn't help either.

So my simple question is: Why is my setting of `spark.shuffle.partitions` being ignored and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I do feel a bit stupid now.

I need to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and not `spark.shuffle.partitions`.

I was expecting Spark to throw an error on getting a setting that doesn't exist and when that didn't happen I thought it was okay.